# Let's get critical: Aug 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Parenting Stack Exchange](http://parenting.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Preparing 3 year old for new baby?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/8277/preparing-3-year-old-for-new-baby)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [What are the causes and remedies of constipation in toddlers?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/8349/what-are-the-causes-and-remedies-of-constipation-in-toddlers)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [How to latch a newborn properly?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/8353/how-to-latch-a-newborn-properly)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How do you pass hand-me-downs to a younger sibling without fostering resentment?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/8304/how-do-you-pass-hand-me-downs-to-a-younger-sibling-without-fostering-resentment)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How to get schizophrenia and bipolar kids to take medication?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/8416/how-to-get-schizophrenia-and-bipolar-kids-to-take-medication)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What to do if my kids would not listen to my reasoning?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/what-to-do-if-my-kids-would-not-listen-to-my-reasoning)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Is feeding the right time to talk and read to a kid?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/8264/is-feeding-the-right-time-to-talk-and-read-to-a-kid)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [How to clean the vagina of a newborn?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/8331/how-to-clean-the-vagina-of-a-newborn)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How to know whether I am producing sufficient breast milk?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/8339/how-to-know-whether-i-am-producing-sufficient-breast-milk)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How can I help my toddler with his booger problem?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/8394/how-can-i-help-my-toddler-with-his-booger-problem)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)